# How to access a property declared in a viewController which is assigned to UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement a application which has five tabs totally. Each of tabs corresponds to a view controller, such as viewController1~viewController5.

For the viewController4, I add the navigationController on it in AppDelegate.m as following:

```
viewController4 = [[iPhone_ASRAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhone_ASRAViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
```

In the iPhone_ASRViewController class, I have declared a property in .h file as following:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *student_id;
```

Then, I want to access the student_id(set the student_id) which is declared in iPhone_ASRViewController in the FirstViewController, and implement in FirstViewController.m as following:

```
iPhone_ASRAViewController *iphone_ASRAVC= [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
iphone_ASRAVC.student_id=[stu_class stringByAppendingString:stu_id]; 
//stu_class and stu_id is the text field declared in the FirstViewController.
```

Ideally, when a certain button which is implemented in the FirstViewController class is pushed by users, the value of student_id will also be set to iPhone_ASRAViewController class.

Unfortunately, the app will crash when users push the button. Error msgs as following:

```
[UINavigationController setStudent_id:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9341170
```

Can someone provide me with some ideas/solutions to debug, please?

Comment: i don't know where to start. where did you implement the setter ?, why readwrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, wenn the view controllers in a tab bar have (or better are) navigation controllers, then the `viewControllers` array of the tab bar controller contains navigation controllers instead. Actually, you (or your storyboard) put them in! 
It may well be a mix of view controllers and navigation controllers, depending of what was actually set upon creation or reconfiguration (if any) of the tab bar.

So I'd sugest to receive the object from `viewContollers` at the given index into something of type ID. Then check whether it is a navigation controller (use `isKindOfClass:[iPhone_ASRAViewController class]`) and if so then use it directly. If not then check whether it is of class UINavigationConroller (or the other way around - what ever is more convenient for you) and if so fetch its topViewController property and go from there.

Edit: Added in response to comments:

```
id someController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
if (someController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]) {
  someController = [someController topViewController]; //re-using someController
}
// someController should be a UIViewController from here onwards. But you may double check if you want.
if (someController isKindOfClass:[iPhone_ASRAViewController class]) {
  iPhone_ASRAViewController *myIPhone_ASRAViewController (iPhone_ASRAViewController*) someController; 
  // you may now savely access those properties that are unique to your custom view controller class
}
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestions. Because I am the beginner of objc,so I didn't got your point about "receive the object from viewContollers". Can you describe it in more detail? I am so grateful for your help.

On the other hand, I found that When I declare a new instance of iPhone_ASRAViewController in the FirstViewController to access the stu_id. This method seems to conflict with navController1 I declared in the AppDelegate.m.

Comment: I meant to access the `viewControllers` property of the UITabBarController and get the 3rd (in your example) Element. You did that alreay. All what I suggest is to store it in an `id` type varualbe at first and then check, whether it is a navigation controller or a view controller (respectively your subclass of `UIViewController`). In your case it could be that it is always a navigation controller. But checking upon that is a more general and therefore less error prone and reusable approach.

Comment: Hi, Hermann,
You REALLY do me a very big favor and kindness!!!!I followed your suggestions/methods to resolve problems, and the app can  work well now.
I feel truly grateful for your assistance.
Thank you with all my heart.